# Can user inputs be be printed iteratively?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am taking multiple inputs from the user and trying to find the most efficient way of printing them. I know we could ask the user to input individually and then print a list like this:

```
list = []

for i in range(dish_no):
    item = input(f"tell us your favourite dishes: ")
    list.append(item)

print(list)
```

But i am wondering if there is a way to take all the inputs at once and iteratively print them or append them. for example i tried:

```
item1, item2= input("tell us your favourite dishes: ").split()

for i in range(2):
    print(item{i})
```

```
item1, item2 = input("tell us your favourite dishes: ").split()
food_list = []

for i in range(2):
    food_list.append(item{i})
```

Comment: you can insert all your dishes as a string separated by comma. Then use split(',') to transform this string into a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can input all dishes with a single input separating them with commas and later transform this string into a list using `split(",")`

```
items = input(f"tell us your favourite dishes separated by comma: ")

# split the string items into a list of dishes
food_list = items.split(',')
```

Then you can just print it as a list

```
print(food_list)
```

Or iterate the elements and print each one individually. You can use `enumerate` if you want also the index so you can enumerate the elements when printing them.

```
for i, elem in enumerate(food_list, 1):
    print(f"{i}: {elem}")

1 Tomato Consomme and Smoked Ricotta Tortelli.
2 Quail Legs with Tamarind Glaze and Fig Chutney.
3 Slow Poached Egg with Bacon Dust & Parmesan Foam
4 Turkey Bolognese Polenta Nests
```